# I want to combine two unequal arrays and want to display key from one and value from the other nad also the repeatation

Tags: php

I have two arrays in Php

```
$array1= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ;
$array2= array('red','yellow','green') ;
```

now I have to print both the array in such a way that value of `1` should be `'red'` , value of `2` should be `'yellow'`, value of `3` should be `'green'`, value of `4` should be `'red'` ,value of `5` should be `'green'`, value of `7` should be again `'red'` and so on up to .....  10.
How can I do this? 
I used `array_combine()` function but it is not working because these are two unequal arrays.
 So plz help me out.

Comment: usual `foreach`

Comment: before asking for help, you have to show us that you tried by yourself. tell us what you have tried and we will be glad to help correct your code

Answer (score 0):

I not totally sure that the next code is optimal but it should do what you are want

```
function mapper($num)
{
    $index= $num % $item;
    return "{$num} $array2";
}

$array1= array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ;
$array2= array('red','yellow','green');

$mapper = function ($num) use ($array2) {
    $count = count($array2);
    $index=  ( $num -1 ) % $count;
    return "{$num} $array2[$index]";
};

$result = array_map($mapper,$array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
```

To check the code in the sanbox follow the
[link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04757bc6f6980090c34b4c8777f6dd31d45df8cd)

Comment: i need explaination  for this, i am not able to understand this code.